# Using Shopify Auth for a React-Native App

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication, shopify

I am building out a `React-Native` Application, and I would like the users to be able to:

1. Log in to the App with their credentials from our online Shopify Store.
2. Create a new user in the app, which makes a new user on the Shopify Store.
3. Backup user info in our Firebase Database.

So far, we have been able to get logins working only for admin side accounts, not for customers. Does anyone know of the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to use Shopify Plus if you want customer login info in any App outside of Shopify

Comment: @DavidLazar Really trying to avoid this option if possible, thats an extra $2000/month

Comment: business is business.